# Feature Mismatch while trying new dataset. Model features more than input features

Tags: python-3.x

I have created a Random Forest Classification model. It's working fine when I tested it on test set.

Then I pickled the model. 
Now, I am using another set lets call in "Production Set". 
I am loading the model pickle file and passing the production set data to the model for predictions

I am getting error:

> ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input.  Model n_features is 87 and input n_features is 63

In production set I will have only one line/row of data or max to 10rows. Hence the number of features will be less than my features in the model but will remain the subset of the features in the model. Below is my code:

```
from DataPreparationv3 import Data_Preprocess # custom function for datapreprocess
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pickle

pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

Base_Data = pd.read_csv('Validate2.csv')
DataReady = Data_Preprocess(Base_Data)
del Base_Data

# load the model from disk
filename = 'Genralized_CTA_Predictions.pkl'
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
result = loaded_model.predict(DataReady)
```

How to solve this problem. Please help.

Regards

Sudhir

Comment: Requesting your help and guidance

Comment: Please let me know if you require anymore info to guide me.

Comment: @aaronchall can you please help.